# How do I get the output CLASS file names after compiling Java files in C#?

Tags: c#, java

So, when you compile Java (*.java) into a class file (*.class), the name of the file can change, as well as the extension of the file. If I have a piece of code in C# that compiles the java code into class files, how would I then get the names of those output class files in C#?

Comment: How is your C# code compiling the java code? Can you post the C# code?

Comment: If the class is public, then its filename should be the same as the class name.

Comment: It just executes javac on the system.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a .java file,  you will get a .class file for each class declared in the file. This means the primary class, which must match the file name, and any inner classes and anonymous classes.

```
class Outer {

    static class Inner {

    }

    public void run() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // code here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

will produce:

```
Outer.class
Outer$Inner.class
Outer$1.class
```

So assuming you are building to a clean directory, you can get a list of files with the .class extensions and get a list of all classes in `Foo.java` by knowing there will be one that is  `Foo.class` and others that start with `Foo$`. Now this could potentially be broken, as you are technically allowed to have your own classes that have `$` in them, but you are strongly advised to not do so, since it typically denotes a system generated class file.

Comment: What if Java Class Files contains Nested Classes ?

Comment: @Cody does my example not already use nested classes? Or perhaps we're operating under a different definition. I'm using the one defined here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the Compiler Options like : **javac -d directory** 
Use **Process** Class to Start the **java compiler**

```
Process.StartInfo.FileName = "javac";
```

First you should generate a Temporary Dir .

```
Directory.Create(Application.StartupPath + @"/TemporaryJavaFiles");
Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d "+Application.StartupPath + @"/TemporaryJavaFiles";
Process.Start();
string[] JavaClassess = Directory.GetFilesApplication.StartupPath + @"/TemporaryJavaFiles");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@directoryString, "*.class");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `javac -verbose yourclass.java` and search for lines starting with [wrote] in output.